# Convert delimiter data to rows and columns

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

i have RAW data in Results column like below with semicolon separated.

**Case ID;HPMN;VPMN;IMSI;Case Creation Time;Case Reporting Time;Case Closure Time;Last Call Time;Fraud Type;Reporting Remarks;SDR Value - Created (TAP);SDR Value - Created (NRT);SDR Value - Reported (TAP);SDR Value - Reported (NRT);SDR Value - Closed (TAP);SDR Value - Closed (NRT);SDR Value - Total (TAP);SDR Value - Total (NRT);SDR Value - Fraud Loss (TAP);SDR Value - Fraud Loss (NRT);Case Status ID;Case Status;Analyst Name - Assigned;Analyst Name - Closure;Group;Flag;7014472;NLXLT;ESPAT;204046205787443;17.05.2018 00:00;17.05.2018 05:57;;18.05.2018 06:45:09;High Usage Request ;;10.35;0; 10.35;0;0;0;20.72;0;10.37;0;512;Pending;Gloriana;Lokesh;AllRoamingGroup P1;non-hosted;7014473;OMNNT;ARETC;422030204010256;17.05.2018 00:01;17.05.2018 05:57;;15.05.2018 19:47:09;OMNNT 10MB & 50 SDRs;;51.35 ;0;51.35;0;0;0;51.35 ;0;0;0;512;Pending;Gloriana;Jordan;AllRoamingGroup P1;non-hosted;7014474;NLXLT;CZECM;204046868687429;17.05.2018 00:02;;17.05.2018 00:24;17.05.2018 15:36:23;Call third country;;0;0;0;0;0;0;.44;0;.44;0;2048;Closed Not Fraud;Gloriana;Gloriana;AllRoamingGroup P1;non-hosted;
7014475;DOMCL;PRICL;370021204427525;17.05.2018 00:03;;17.05.2018 00:26;17.05.2018 22:44:19;Call third country;;0;230.41;0;0;0;230.41;1.94;1200.07;1.94;969.66;2048;Closed Not Fraud;Gloriana;Gloriana;AllRoamingGroup P1;non-hosted;**

But i need output in this way

[image: But i need output in this way]

I tried regular expression but not able to get the desired output

Comment: Is the data in a table? Give exact sample data and your expected out in terms or SQL relate-able tables.

Comment: Format your data . It is barely readable.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Unfortunately  data is in single line format

Comment: So, you are receiving this whole data as a single string from somewhere and you want to split it into rows and columns?

Comment: @KaushikNayak : Yes you are correct

Comment: I would expect  atleast some effort from you in coming up with a sql or procedure, but looks like you got your complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

This will get the first 16 columns.... but you can just add extra columns as needed following the same pattern:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac59e/14)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'Case ID;HPMN;VPMN;IMSI;Case Creation Time;Case Reporting Time;Case Closure Time;Last Call Time;Fraud Type;Reporting Remarks;SDR Value - Created (TAP);SDR Value - Created (NRT);SDR Value - Reported (TAP);SDR Value - Reported (NRT);SDR Value - Closed (TAP);SDR Value - Closed (NRT);SDR Value - Total (TAP);SDR Value - Total (NRT);SDR Value - Fraud Loss (TAP);SDR Value - Fraud Loss (NRT);Case Status ID;Case Status;Analyst Name - Assigned;Analyst Name - Closure;Group;Flag;7014472;NLXLT;ESPAT;204046205787443;17.05.2018 00:00;17.05.2018 05:57;;18.05.2018 06:45:09;High Usage Request ;;10.35;0; 10.35;0;0;0;20.72;0;10.37;0;512;Pending;Gloriana;Lokesh;AllRoamingGroup P1;non-hosted;7014473;OMNNT;ARETC;422030204010256;17.05.2018 00:01;17.05.2018 05:57;;15.05.2018 19:47:09;OMNNT 10MB & 50 SDRs;;51.35 ;0;51.35;0;0;0;51.35 ;0;0;0;512;Pending;Gloriana;Jordan;AllRoamingGroup P1;non-hosted;7014474;NLXLT;CZECM;204046868687429;17.05.2018 00:02;;17.05.2018 00:24;17.05.2018 15:36:23;Call third country;;0;0;0;0;0;0;.44;0;.44;0;2048;Closed Not Fraud;Gloriana;Gloriana;AllRoamingGroup P1;non-hosted; 7014475;DOMCL;PRICL;370021204427525;17.05.2018 00:03;;17.05.2018 00:26;17.05.2018 22:44:19;Call third country;;0;230.41;0;0;0;230.41;1.94;1200.07;1.94;969.66;2048;Closed Not Fraud;Gloriana;Gloriana;AllRoamingGroup P1;non-hosted;' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH data (
  value,
  lvl,
  maxlvl,
  Case_ID,
  HPMN,
  VPMN,
  IMSI,
  Case_Creation_Time,
  Case_Reporting_Time,
  Case_Closure_Time,
  Last_Call_Time,
  Fraud_Type,
  Reporting_Remarks,
  SDR_Value_Created_TAP,
  SDR_Value_Created_NRT,
  SDR_Value_Reported_TAP,
  SDR_Value_Reported_NRT,
  SDR_Value_Closed_TAP,
  SDR_Value_Closed_NRT
) AS (
  SELECT value,
         1,
         REGEXP_COUNT( value, '([^;]*);' ) / 26,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 +  1, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 +  2, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 +  3, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 +  4, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 +  5, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 +  6, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 +  7, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 +  8, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 +  9, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 + 10, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 + 11, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 + 12, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 + 13, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 + 14, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 + 15, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1,   0*26 + 16, NULL, 1 )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         lvl+1,
         maxlvl,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 +  1, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 +  2, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 +  3, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 +  4, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 +  5, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 +  6, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 +  7, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 +  8, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 +  9, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 + 10, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 + 11, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 + 12, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 + 13, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 + 14, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 + 15, NULL, 1 ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^;]*);', 1, lvl*26 + 16, NULL, 1 )
  FROM   data
  WHERE  lvl < maxlvl
)
SELECT Case_ID,
       HPMN,
       VPMN,
       IMSI,
       Case_Creation_Time,
       Case_Reporting_Time,
       Case_Closure_Time,
       Last_Call_Time,
       Fraud_Type,
       Reporting_Remarks,
       SDR_Value_Created_TAP,
       SDR_Value_Created_NRT,
       SDR_Value_Reported_TAP,
       SDR_Value_Reported_NRT,
       SDR_Value_Closed_TAP,
       SDR_Value_Closed_NRT
FROM   data
WHERE  lvl > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac59e/14/0)**:

```
|  CASE_ID |  HPMN |  VPMN |            IMSI | CASE_CREATION_TIME | CASE_REPORTING_TIME | CASE_CLOSURE_TIME |      LAST_CALL_TIME |           FRAUD_TYPE | REPORTING_REMARKS | SDR_VALUE_CREATED_TAP | SDR_VALUE_CREATED_NRT | SDR_VALUE_REPORTED_TAP | SDR_VALUE_REPORTED_NRT | SDR_VALUE_CLOSED_TAP | SDR_VALUE_CLOSED_NRT |
|----------|-------|-------|-----------------|--------------------|---------------------|-------------------|---------------------|----------------------|-------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
|  7014472 | NLXLT | ESPAT | 204046205787443 |   17.05.2018 00:00 |    17.05.2018 05:57 |            (null) | 18.05.2018 06:45:09 |  High Usage Request  |            (null) |                 10.35 |                     0 |                  10.35 |                      0 |                    0 |                    0 |
|  7014473 | OMNNT | ARETC | 422030204010256 |   17.05.2018 00:01 |    17.05.2018 05:57 |            (null) | 15.05.2018 19:47:09 | OMNNT 10MB & 50 SDRs |            (null) |                51.35  |                     0 |                  51.35 |                      0 |                    0 |                    0 |
|  7014474 | NLXLT | CZECM | 204046868687429 |   17.05.2018 00:02 |              (null) |  17.05.2018 00:24 | 17.05.2018 15:36:23 |   Call third country |            (null) |                     0 |                     0 |                      0 |                      0 |                    0 |                    0 |
|  7014475 | DOMCL | PRICL | 370021204427525 |   17.05.2018 00:03 |              (null) |  17.05.2018 00:26 | 17.05.2018 22:44:19 |   Call third country |            (null) |                     0 |                230.41 |                      0 |                      0 |                    0 |               230.41 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 +  1 ), ';' ) AS Case_ID,
       RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 +  2 ), ';' ) AS HPMN,
       RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 +  3 ), ';' ) AS VPMN,
       RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 +  4 ), ';' ) AS IMSI,
       RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 +  5 ), ';' ) AS Case_Creation_Time,
       RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 +  6 ), ';' ) AS Case_Reporting_Time,
       RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 +  7 ), ';' ) AS Case_Closure_Time,
       RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 +  8 ), ';' ) AS Last_Call_Time,
       RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 +  9 ), ';' ) AS Fraud_Type,
       RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 + 10 ), ';' ) AS Reporting_Remarks,
       RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 + 11 ), ';' ) AS SDR_Value_Created_TAP,
       RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 + 12 ), ';' ) AS SDR_Value_Created_NRT,
       RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 + 13 ), ';' ) AS SDR_Value_Reported_TAP,
       RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 + 14 ), ';' ) AS SDR_Value_Reported_NRT,
       RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 + 15 ), ';' ) AS SDR_Value_Closed_TAP,
       RTRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.*?;', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE*26 + 16 ), ';' ) AS SDR_Value_Closed_NRT
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.value, '.*?;', 1, LEVEL*26 + 1 ) IS NOT NULL
           )
           AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       ) l
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac59e/14/1)**:

```
|  CASE_ID |  HPMN |  VPMN |            IMSI | CASE_CREATION_TIME | CASE_REPORTING_TIME | CASE_CLOSURE_TIME |      LAST_CALL_TIME |           FRAUD_TYPE | REPORTING_REMARKS | SDR_VALUE_CREATED_TAP | SDR_VALUE_CREATED_NRT | SDR_VALUE_REPORTED_TAP | SDR_VALUE_REPORTED_NRT | SDR_VALUE_CLOSED_TAP | SDR_VALUE_CLOSED_NRT |
|----------|-------|-------|-----------------|--------------------|---------------------|-------------------|---------------------|----------------------|-------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
|  7014472 | NLXLT | ESPAT | 204046205787443 |   17.05.2018 00:00 |    17.05.2018 05:57 |            (null) | 18.05.2018 06:45:09 |  High Usage Request  |            (null) |                 10.35 |                     0 |                  10.35 |                      0 |                    0 |                    0 |
|  7014473 | OMNNT | ARETC | 422030204010256 |   17.05.2018 00:01 |    17.05.2018 05:57 |            (null) | 15.05.2018 19:47:09 | OMNNT 10MB & 50 SDRs |            (null) |                51.35  |                     0 |                  51.35 |                      0 |                    0 |                    0 |
|  7014474 | NLXLT | CZECM | 204046868687429 |   17.05.2018 00:02 |              (null) |  17.05.2018 00:24 | 17.05.2018 15:36:23 |   Call third country |            (null) |                     0 |                     0 |                      0 |                      0 |                    0 |                    0 |
|  7014475 | DOMCL | PRICL | 370021204427525 |   17.05.2018 00:03 |              (null) |  17.05.2018 00:26 | 17.05.2018 22:44:19 |   Call third country |            (null) |                     0 |                230.41 |                      0 |                      0 |                    0 |               230.41 |
```

Comment: @Anil Updated with a second version that I think will work in 10g (but cannot test as I don't have that version available).

Comment: i have replaced value(RESULT), table_name(ME_MACH_FRAUDPROT_REPORT) with my column name and table. I see ORA-00904: "T"."RESULT": invalid identifier error

Comment: i'm getting ORA-00904: "T"."RESULT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" for line **CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.result, '.*?;', 1, LEVEL*26 + 1 ) IS NOT NULL**

Comment: @Anil It works on 11g and I don't have a 10g instance to test it on so this is one you will have to debug on your own as I cannot replicate your error on the instances I have available.

Comment: @Anil : I would suggest you to sit with the people /owners of the application that generate the data, persuade them and agree upon providing you data in a standard format : say csv, xml, json etc.Then you could easily use sqlloader, sql developer or whatever. Ideally,It should not be the job of database code to sanitise your message data text. SQL/PLSQL is still powerful to do such tasks, but you end up with solutions that may be hard for you to maintain without the required understanding of how it works.